# QGIS Mesh Calculator output file (.dat)

Tags: qgis, netcdf, mesh

I want to understand Mesh Calculator in QGIS 3.8.3 to make calculation between two variables of a NetCDF file. Each of these variables has [lon, lat, time] dimensions. The calculation is done smoothly (which is <s>suspiciously</s>  amazingly quick) and produces a binary file with *(.dat)* extension.

This dat file is probably meant for [hydrodynamic modelling software](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_mesh/mesh_properties.html) but I cannot access them.

Is there a way to read this dat file by QGIS, or convert it to other formats for further analysis?

---

*[Edit]* ... Poor choice of word. As commented by Gabriel De Luca, it works lightning fast.

Comment: From QGIS 3.12 you are able to choose the output driver/format in the mesh calculator for your results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it as a new dataset in the source layer through the *Assign Extra Dataset to Mesh* button, in the *Source* tab of the layer properties.

[image: 1]

The Dataset will be added to the layer, but not saved in the layer file. It remains as a group of data in a separate file.

This test was made with a grib file. The algebra was just a weather condition.

[image: 2]

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel De Luca ! That works (=^ ^=)...... (Sorry for this late reply. I had been struggling to export them in one nc file then... and given up finally).

Comment: You`re welcome, @Kazuhito! Review the temporary information. My original data has a 3 hour step and it seems that this information was lost in algebra. Or maybe I made a mistake, it was a test. And I was also surprised how quickly the operation was performed!